# Flutter: Deploy multiple apps at once

Tags: flutter

We have 13 apps that are exactly the same in source code, one difference is app name.

Currently, whenever we have an update to deploy we have to manually do it to every developer account. Is there a way to combine all apps into one source code and deploy it to each account?

Comment: You could use something like a build flag to change the name and then distribute them to all the separate accounts using something like fastlane. But let me ask you this question: Why do you have so many developer accounts? If only the name changes, then find a common name, that fits for all apps and just deploy it once. Seems like the easiest option IMHO.

Comment: We build variations of our app for clients and create a developer account under there business name.

Answer (score 1):

If the deploying to multiple accounts is a must, then you can also considering automating this by using the API which both the platforms, Android and IOS have and there are options like [fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/) available which make the process fairly easy

If you can switch to a single developer account, then flavours could be an easy way out

Flutter Flavours is exactly for this purpose. A flavour is analogous to say ice cream, well the base content is same but you would like to have a different flavour always right? The best part is you can do something for both Android as well as IOS

You can read about Flutter Flavours [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/flavors)

Comment: Totally agree. If really the only difference between all apps is, that the name is different, multiple accounts do not make sense. Maybe the OP could elaborate a little bit further what kind of app it's about.